# Adding two core data derived attributes on an entity causes crash when adding object to that entity

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes, ios13

I am trying to add derived attributes, introduced in iOS 13, to an app. The issue arises when creating a new version of the `xcdatamodel` with two new attributes in Entity A. Each of those attributes is a boolean, and is set as `derived` and `optional`. Each references an `optional` boolean on Entity B. None of the attributes on either entity is set as `scalar`. For each new derived attribute the derivation is basically a simple, to-one keypath to an object on Entity B. When I add just one of the new attributes - either one - the app functions fine. As soon as I add another attribute, the app crashes on inserting a new object into Entity A. Expanding on this, I find that adding more than one derived attribute at all to any entity is causing a crash upon inserting a new object into that entity.

The error is simply

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

with no reason given.

This seems like crazy behavior to me. I can't find anyone else having a similar issue. Is this expected behavior for Core Data in iOS 13?

Comment: If anyone could do a simple test of this and let me know if it is happening to them too, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, just tested.  Same problem.  You're not going mad.  Or we both are.

Comment: @pbasdf did you happen to download the next Xcode Beta? If so, is this still an issue there? I don't have enough room on my laptop to download it.

Comment: @pbasdf this appears NOT to be corrected in iOS 13.4

Comment: I honestly don't see how this is not fixed yet.

Comment: @pbasdf are you by any chance using Objective-C?

Comment: Yes - why do you ask?

Comment: Because I'm using Objective-C also. Seems like very few people are using Objective-C anymore and I couldn't figure out why they wouldn't have fixed this with so many users and this being such a huge bug. My guess is that somehow it is Objective-C related.